# How to translate the C language loop (do ... while) in CLIPS?

Tags: c, clips

Suppose following portion of code in C:

```
void function(int n,int x)
{
int i,j;
int max=5;
int p[max]; // for example: p[max]={{100,1,100,3,10}};
...
...

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(i!=x)
        {
            j=i;
            do
            {
                j=p[j];     
            }
            while(j!=x);
        }
...
}
```

I try following in CLIPS, but the condition in while loop is evaluated before [do] execution, which is not the case in the portion of C language code above where [do] is executed befor while loop:

```
(deftemplate q
    (slot line (type INTEGER)(default 1))
    (slot column (type INTEGER))
    (slot value (type INTEGER))
)

(deffacts Data ; for example
(q (line 1)(column 1)(value 100))
(q (line 1)(column 2)(value 1))
(q (line 1)(column 3)(value 100))
(q (line 1)(column 4)(value 3))
(q (line 1)(column 5)(value 10))
)

(deffunction function (?n ?x)
    (loop-for-count (?i 1  ?n)
        (if (!= ?i ?x) 
        then
            (bind ?j ?i)
            (while (!= ?j ?x) do
                (do-for-all-facts ((?q q))
                    (and 
                        (= (fact-slot-value ?q line) 1)
                        (= (fact-slot-value ?q column) ?j)
                    )
                    (bind ?j (fact-slot-value ?q value))
                ) 
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Question: Is it a correct code ? Any help will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, put ?q instead ?distance

Comment: You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67050393/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Do ... while is not directly supported, but you can put a break statement at the end of the while body to implement that functionality:

```
(deffunction function (?n ?x)
    (loop-for-count (?i 1  ?n)
        (if (!= ?i ?x) 
        then
            (bind ?j ?i)
            (while TRUE do
                (do-for-all-facts ((?q q))
                    (and 
                        (= (fact-slot-value ?q line) 1)
                        (= (fact-slot-value ?q column) ?j)
                    )
                    (bind ?j (fact-slot-value ?q value))
                ) 
                (if (!= ?j ?x) then (break))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your concern and help, M. Riley.

Answer (score 0):

Ok general dumb overpowered solution: define a macro kind of like this (pseudocode I never quite got the hang of lisp syntax)

```
(defmacro do-while (@test @body) (
   (body)
   (while (!= ?j ?x) do (body))
))
```

I think you can even skip the middle man and embed the loop directly into the recursive expansion but I simply don't know enough to force it to tail-recurse.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, M. Joshua.